# How to load a view in angular directly through a URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to access a view in my Angular app. It does work when I go there through a button however when I want to access that view via a link (e.g. by clicking on one) or when I am refreshing the page, it does not seem to load my state/view. This is a snippet of my config.js:

```
.state('test', {
    parent: 'site',
    url: '/test',
    templateUrl: 'views/index_test.html'
})
```

Also, I do get a response from the server but I think Angular cannot integrate my partial view into the index.html.

Comment: have you placed `ui-view` on the page to render partial view into it.?

Comment: Yes I do have ui-view in my index.html.

Comment: I mean in this `site` state should have `ui-view` as well to render `test`(child of site state) template in it

Comment: Yeah, `site` has
`.state('site', {
  abstract: true,
  template: '<div ui-view/>'
}`

Comment: are there any errors showing up in the console? I noticed you have a comma at the end of your ```templateUrl``` line.

Comment: No I don't get any error logs in the console. As I said, I seems to be working if I go to that state via a button with ui-sref but if I click a link with that URL it won't load the template.

Comment: how is the link setup? Are you using href or ui-sref?